# EF Core one-to-many relationship beside another foreign key property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have these two models (irrelevant properties are not present):

```
// based on Identity
public class User {
  public long? CityId { get; set; }
  public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class City : Base {
}

public class Base {
  public string CreatorId { get; set; }
  public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the problem is that EF Core can't determine the one-to-many relationship between `User` and `City` and it thinks that there's a one-to-one relationship (I remember I hadn't such problem with EF 6).

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
>   relationship between 'User.City' and 'City.Creator'. To identify the
>   child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key
>   property. If these navigations should not be part of the same
>   relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.

So, I'm forced to add another navigation property to `City`:

```
public class City : Base {
  public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem persists:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'City.Users' of type 'IList'. Either manually configure
>   the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I ended up using Fluent API and `ModelBuilder`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<City>(u => u.City)
            .WithMany(c => c.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.CityId);
```

Using Fluent API, we can remove that `Users` navigation property inside `City` and call an empty `WithMany` (see the first comment):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<City>(u => u.City)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.CityId);
```

Is it the only way? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I had more properties like `CreatorId` (for example `LastEditorId`) on the `Base` class in the EF 6 version, and it still could figure out the relationships. Tried this in the EF Core version. Not working.

Comment: You dont need to have IList<User> Users you can leave withMany() empty. I dont understand your problem you dont like to use fluent api?

Comment: @CrazyBaran Thanks. I didn't know that. I'll update the question. I like Fluent API when it's really needed. I just want to know if using Fluent API is necessary in this case. It used to be working on EF 6.

Comment: Hard to tell I write fluent api for everything to have control. But when you have such construct one property on each site then it naturally that it think it is one to one. How keys are generated? On example in User you didn't have any Id. I asumed that it is something. On City you also remove it. It is named Id?

Comment: @CrazyBaran They were removed for clarity. They're named `Id` on both models.

Comment: So from my understanding it is good behaviour of ef core, that it made one to one in this case. There is nothing additional what could told ef core to behavie differently. So you need left with fluent api I think.

Comment: @CrazyBaran I think that's it. Still don't understand how EF 6 could manage :) Thanks anyway. Time to get used to Fluent API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the `City` that inherits from the `Base` model contains all the properties of the parent class, so that the relationship between `City` and `User` is one-to-one, not one-to-many.

In fact , [Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx) follows the same convention as Entity Framework 6.x conventions for one-to-many relationship. The only difference is that EF Core creates a foreign key column with the same name as navigation property name and not as `<NavigationPropertyName>_<PrimaryKeyPropertyName>`.

Fluent API specify the model configuration that you can with data annotations as well as some additional functionality that can not be possible with data annotations.

- In Entity Framework Core, the [ModelBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder?view=efcore-2.1) class acts as a Fluent API.
- We can configure many different things by using it because it provides more configuration options than data annotation attributes.
- Data annotations and the fluent API can be used together, but precedence of **Fluent API > data annotations > default conventions.**

You could refer to the links below to help you better understand Fluent Api :

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx

https://entityframeworkcore.com/model-fluent-api

Comment: Thanks. Some useful info. That seems to be the case, but I can't understand how EF 6 could do this. The strange thing is that I had more properties like `CreatorId` (for example `LastEditorId`) on the `Base` class in the EF 6 version, and it still worked. But I tried that too in EF Core; not working.